# Ajax не работает

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

у меня вроде простая задача, но не работает:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function (){
    $('#btnnavi').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
        url:"core/as.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data: {offer:document.getElementById("offer").value, 
                type_ps:document.getElementById("type_ps").value,
                summa:document.getElementById("summa").value},
        success:function(data){
            if (data[0] === 0) { //check success querry
                alert( "ok: " + data )
            } //close if ~check success querry
            else { // check  error
                alert( "не ок: " + data )
            } // close else ~check  error
        }// close success
    }); // close ajax
}); //close click
}); //close window.onload
</script>
```

соответственно форма:

```
<form action="/" method="post" name="contact_form">
<input  type="text" id="offer" required>
<input type="hidden" id="type_ps" value="WebMoney">
<input  type="number"  id="summa"  >
<button  id="btnnavi">Получить выплату!</button>
</form>
```

core/as.php - отдаёт в json, или ноль или текст ошибки.

Но почему то не работает( .... помогите советом.

Comment: если не заполнить форму и нажать кнопку - работает (через раз)...

Comment: Пути к скриптам верные?

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под "не работает"? Страница перезагружается?

Comment: @mJeevas пути верные, походу да - перезагружается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не работает, потому-что параллельно с повешенным обработчиком у вас срабатывает стандартная отправка формы.

`<button>`, как и `<input type="submit">` может отправить форму.

Как решить:

Можно выключить стандартную отправку по клику на button

```
    $('#btnnavi').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;
```

Целиком:

```
<script>
$(function (){
    $('#btnnavi').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        $.ajax({
        url:"core/as.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data: {offer:document.getElementById("offer").value, 
                type_ps:document.getElementById("type_ps").value,
                summa:document.getElementById("summa").value},
        success:function(data){
            if (data[0] === 0) { //check success querry
                alert( "ok: " + data )
            } //close if ~check success querry
            else { // check  error
                alert( "не ок: " + data )
            } // close else ~check  error
        }// close success
    }); // close ajax
}); //close click
}); //close window.onload
</script>
```

Или как вариант:

Добавить к `<button>` атрибут `type="button"`

Или не использовать форму

Answer (score 0):

достаточно поменять форму на

```
<form action="/" method="post" name="contact_form">
<input  type="text" id="offer" required>
<input type="hidden" id="type_ps" value="WebMoney">
<input  type="number"  id="summa"  >
<input type="button"  id="btnnavi" value="Получить выплату!">
</form>
```